# How do I prevent creating a new object ID each time I restart the app, on Parse?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, database-backups, objectid

I am trying to back up data on my app by clicking the 'Save' button - each time I start the app and click this button after entering some text, it creates a new Object ID field on parse database (It updates on the same ID if I do not close the app).

This prevents me from retrieving the same data as last saved when I restart the app.

I want to be able to update the data each time on the same object ID after I restart the app. Is this possible? Or will it only be possible if I use Parse User feature?

Also, I want the data to be retrieved automatically when I start the app - instead of the current where it only retrieves when refreshed.

Please help!

Here are my relevant pieces of code for main java file, where 'seteditTxt' is the id of the editText item where data is written and retrieved to:

```java
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity
implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

  String eventTxt;
  EditText seteditTxt;
  ParseObject Events = new ParseObject("Events");

  @
  Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {...
  }

  @
  Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    seteditTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.seteditTxt);

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
      updatelocalData();
      updateData();
    }

    if (id == R.id.action_example) {
      eventTxt = seteditTxt.getText().toString();
      Events.put("EventName", eventTxt);
      Events.saveEventually(new SaveCallback() {
        public void done(ParseException e) {
          if (e == null) {
            // Saved successfully.
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          } else {
            // The save failed.
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to Save", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
        }
      });
      Events.pinInBackground();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }

  public void updateData() {
    ParseQuery < ParseObject > query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Events");
    query.getInBackground("d51GM3syxp", new GetCallback < ParseObject > () {
      public void done(ParseObject Events, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
          // gameScore will be your game score
          String Txt = Events.getString("EventName");
          seteditTxt.setText(Txt);

        } else {
          // something went wrong
          System.out.print("Error in parse retrieving");
        }
      }
    });
  }

  public void updatelocalData() {
    ParseQuery < ParseObject > query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Events");
    query.fromLocalDatastore();
    query.getInBackground("d51GM3syxp", new GetCallback < ParseObject > () {
      public void done(ParseObject Events, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
          // object will be your game score
          String Txt = Events.getString("EventName");
          seteditTxt.setText(Txt);

        } else {
          // something went wrong
          System.out.print("Error in locally retrieving");
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Parse java file:

```java
public class ParseActivity extends Application{

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // Enable Local Datastore.
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

        Parse.initialize(this, "YZG663Azd0yq10GZFLsB8dt5IMtIfKyNEPFf1Ftf", "bEKK3biC93WFWNLInijqJwnWHJCM8Kl7guPViwqQ");
    }
}
```

I have searched through a lot of websites and tutorials but I cant seem to understand what the method is to follow.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you put in a new text and save it on your "EventName" column, a new ID will be generated. This is because you're inserting an entirely new data entry under the "EventName" column, and each new data entry has its own unique ID.
I would suggest a different way to store and retrieve data. Maybe consider storing a unique user ID with each event name, and only fetching those events by this particular user. For example:

```
Events.put("EventName", eventTxt);
Events.put("EventUser", uniqueUserName); //add a unique user name with each event
  Events.saveEventually(new SaveCallback() {
```

and retrieval:

```
  ParseQuery < ParseObject > query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Events");
  query.whereEqualTo("EventUser", uniqueUserName);
  query.findInBackground....
```

For your second question: To fetch data automatically when the app starts, just call your `updateLocalData()` and `updateData()` methods in the `onResume()` function of your activity. Very simply.

Comment: My retrieval was in my fragment so I added it to the onCreateview of the fragment and it worked for fetching data automatically. 
For fetching the specific event using user ID is a great idea thanks. With this I wouldnt need to use parse user functionality then right? Thanks a tonne will try it now.

Comment: Yes, you do not need to use the user functionality, however, it would make things easier for you if you decide to use it.